# my AVD is not loading what are the setting i should use to run it

Tags: java, android

when i try to load AVD in android there was a message like "location of the android SDK has n ot been setup in the preferences "
what is the solution i should do to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Eclipse,

- Go to Window -> Preferences -> Android
- Browse to YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_INSTALLATION_PATH (wherever you have placed your SDK)
- Hit Apply and OK

Comment: and also there is a message like This Android SDK requires Android Developer To...826.  Please update ADT to the latest version. how to solve that